# How do I get little enough stuff to please the Pope?

Tags: bead-machine-punktasia

I had no problem pleasing the Pope the first time around, but now that I need to get the 5 Enlightenments, I'm stuck. I have $0, FL0, B0, T0, S0/25, W9/25, C0, E1. Workers don't count as things do they? If so, how do I get rid of workers? Do I need to get one more and then I can have 10 go to the Depot leaving me with none?

Comment: I've looked at that page, but I fear it doesn't work for me as Workers are not inputs to the Machine. Unless I'm mistaken and need to grab more hits of the vending machine?

Comment: Everything but Enlightenments count towards the Pope.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the information. Now I know how to handle this situation better (with a new save). I really appreciate your help!